Como solucionar este error: SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
Intento generar un archivo CSV y guardarlo en una carpeta específica, con los registros de una consulta, sin embargo, me aparece este error:
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL

Así es como manejo mi consulta:
DECLARE @ExportSQL NVARCHAR (MAX),
        @Query NVARCHAR (MAX),
        @FilePath NVARCHAR (MAX) = 'C:\Users\Pops\Documents\Proyectos';

SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM Agente;'

SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp "' + @Query  + '"'
               + ' queryout "' + @FilePath + '\Archivo.csv" -c -T -S RYNL036\SQLEXPRESS''';

PRINT @ExportSQL;
EXEC(@ExportSQL);

Cabe mencionar que tengo todos los permisos para escribir en la carpeta y también para usar xp_cmdshell. Gracias

Do posibles problemas 1)C:\Users\Pops\Documents\Proyectos tiene que ser un carpeta accesible por el servidor 2) te faltó un espacio entre estas dos partes ' queryout "' + @FilePath.
